# Consider the increasing list of positive integers that do not contain the digit zero, 1, 2, 3... 9, 11, 12,.... The 2022nd number in this sequence is

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, permutations

> Consider the increasing list of positive integers that do not contain the digit zero, $1, 2, 3, \ldots, 9, 11, 12, \ldots$. The $2022$nd number in this sequence is

so the number of single-digit numbers will be $9$

$2$-digit numbers will be $9 \cdot 9 = 81$

$3$-digit numbers will be $9 \cdot 9 \cdot 9 = 729$

the number of $4$-digit numbers with $1000$'s digit as 1 $= 729$

the number of $4$-digit numbers with the first $2$ digits as 21 through 25 $= 5 \cdot 81=405$

the number of $4$-digit numbers with the first $3$ digits as 261 through 267 $= 7 \cdot 9$

the number of $4$-digit numbers with $4$ digits as 2681 through 2686 $= 6 \cdot 1$

$9+81+729+729+405+63+6 = 2022$

which gives the number is $2686$

but the answer in the book is $2685$

Am I missing something?

Comment: I get the same answer 2686 as you got.

Comment: I also get $2686$.  Obviously, it's a buggy sort of computation.  My first cut incorrectly included $2680$, for instance.

Comment: thanks for confirming

Comment: should i leave this question like this or delete it ?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  It is a bad idea to delete questions when you are new to the site since that could prevent you from asking additional questions.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/42969). After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Comment: @Martin R I'll take care of that from now, thank you

Comment: Basically you are simply converting to a base $9$ system. The only difference is $9$s are acceptable but $0$ are not.  Express $2022$ in base $9$ but replace any $k0$ with $(k-1)9$ and carry if nescessary. So $2022= 2\times 729+6\times 81+8\times 9 + 6$.  So the $2022$ th number is $2686$.  Although I suppose this isn't that useful a comment as one's faith in my reasoning is probably not as strong as the faith in your initial reasoning.  Still.... it's a third person getting the same answer.  (Typos happen).

Comment: @fleablood thanks for confirming